# Meaning of "Dynamic schema supports fluent polymorphism" in MongoDB doc

Tags: mongodb

I am a new in MongoDB and, in its docs, there is the following phrase as a MongoDB advantage:

> Dynamic schema supports fluent polymorphism

What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **polymorphic type** is one whose operations can also be applied to values of some other type, or types. Lets have an example,consider the following mongodb collection of cars

1. A basic car structure

   ```
   {
     "TYPE": "BASIC CAR",
     "MAX_SPEED": 100,
     "MILEAGE": 20,
     "GEARS": 4,
     "FEATURES": [
        {
         "AC": "yes"
        }
     ]
   }
   ```

   The first 4 keys will be same for almost all cars ----> **polymorphic type**
2. A sports car

   ```
   {
     "TYPE": "SPORTS CAR",
     "MAX_SPEED": 300,
     "MILEAGE": 10,
     "GEARS": 8,
     "FEATURES": [
        {
         "AC": "yes"
        },
        {
         "NITRO": "yes"
        },
        {
         "NAVIGATION": "yes"
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ... so on
      ]
      "ADVANCED PROTECTION" : "yes",
      "SENSORS" : [
        {"OBSTACLE" : "yes"}
      ]
     }
   ```

The sports inherits the features of **BASIC CAR** and also has some its own features, that's satisfies **Polymorphism**.

And coming to the part **Dynamic Schema** we can see that structure of document is different for both documents MongoDB won't restrict to a particular structure so that's satisfies **Dynamic Schema**.